# top level await using causes interesting exception

Tags: c#, async-await

In a debug session I saw an exception being thrown within no context ('the name ex does not exist in the current context') BUT after it had returned a value from the try block

[image]

The code looks like this

```
public async Task<int> SomeHandler(){
    await using var connection = await _sqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionAsync();

    try
    {
        const string sql ="..."

        var sqlParams = new
        {
            ...
        };

        var r = await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(sql, sqlParams);

 1. ->  return r; //first returns

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
 2. ->  throw new Exception("log message", ex); // Debugger hits and my QuickWatch says 'the name ex does not exist in the current context'
    }
}
```

`CreateConnectionAsync` is async "all the way down" and the `SomeHandler` is also called async'ly.

Then I read this

*"You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to the using statement, but this isn't a best practice. In this case, after control leaves the using block, the object remains in scope but probably has no access to its unmanaged resources."*

So just for the heck of it I tried to put in connection inside a using.

Like so

```
var connection = await _sqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionAsync();

await using (connection) {
    try {
       ....
```

The exception is still being "caught" but still without a context (the name ex does not exist in the current context)

Then I tried 2 different things.

1. put the `await using var connection = await _sqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionAsync();` inside my try block - then the exception went away
2. removed the await in my using, which also resulted in the exception went away.

   ```
    var connection = await _sqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionAsync();

    using (connection) {
          try {
   ```

My interpretation of this exception being thrown is that it comes from a database connection being out of scope when trying to Dispose.

Am I on the wrong path here ?

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at DisposeAsync method of the connection class

Comment: So this happens only with the debugger attached? In other words there is absolutely no issue when running with Cltr+F5?

Comment: @theemee the connection is a SqlConnection. It inherits from DbConnection which implements IAsyncDisposable.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes. It seems no exception is really there, but I can provoke it by moving code as mentioned above. So I would presume something is off ? :/

Comment: As far as I am concerned, you are debugging the debugger. Good luck with that!

Comment: @DanielFrost I've looked at the source code. The DisposeAsync just calls the synchronous Dispose method and then `return new ValueTask()`. So in this case you don't lose anything by using non-async Dispose

Comment: The SqlConnection documentation also suggests to use `using` instead of `await using`, so I guess that's the one you should use

Comment: @theemee yes, I saw that and then I thought "perhaps the doc has not been updated". But I think you are correct and I will go for that. Leave an answer pls. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielFrost quite likely what you see is the *new* exception being thrown and caught by *using's* exception handler, where there's no `ex` any more. Please clean up the code and post something that actually reproduces the problem, not something like it, or something full of comments and arrows. Include the actual full exception text produced by `Exception.ToString()`.  `ex` is the actual exception, not a context. No exception handler is activated unless there really is an exception. Your own code *throws* a new exception ,which  is *very* unusual.

Comment: @theemee where does it say that?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos stop! Either read the question and try to follow through or stay out of the debate. There is no reason for you to be obnoxious or try to know better. I have updated the question with an image where you can actually see how my debugger behaves - hence context!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "Your own code throws a new exception ,which is very unusual." It's not unusual at all since I wish to log a message and keep the call stack.

Comment: This way you *lose* the stack. Use `throw ex` to avoid this. As for obnoxiousness, when you claim something thousands of developers hadn't noticed, something else is going on. Quite likely this is an artifact of the *debugger*. Since this is an asynchronous method execution may have stopped at some other thread. We can't know from a small screenshot

Comment: If you want good answers for hard problems you *must* include enough information so others can reproduce the problem and investigate it. Could this be a debugger issue? We can't know. What does the Thread Window look like? Unknown. What does the final exception contain? We can't know. Would `logger.Error(ex);` work? I bet it would

Answer (score -1):

I've looked at the source code of SqlConnection and DbConnection. The DisposeAsync just calls the synchronous Dispose method and then `return new ValueTask()`. So in this case you don't lose anything by using non-async Dispose.

The SqlConnection documentation also suggests to use `using` instead of `await using`, so I guess that's the one you should use

Comment: `await using` won't generate errors. As you said, it shouldn't matter at all

Comment: Where in the documentation of `SqlConnection` is the suggestion of not using `await using`?

Comment: @PauloMorgado https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/main/doc/snippets/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/SqlConnection.xml#L21

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i am not saying it generates errors. But when I move the code around as I stated in the question - the exception is no longer present. I am not buying the sentiment that it's the debugger that is causing problems. I get it - the behaviour is odd

Comment: @DanielFrost which exception? `ex` or the new one your code threw? Log and post the exception text. I suspect you'll see the original exception as an `InnerException`. BTW it's a bad idea to wrap and throw like this because it eliminates the stack trace leading to confusion. Like this case

Comment: @DanielFrost that doc link doesn't say that `await using` should be avoided

Comment: @PauloMorgado it doesn't suggest against it, it just uses `using` without await

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you can also look at the implementations of db drivers like [MySqlConnection](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/8.0/MySQL.Data/src/Connection.cs). They do not override DisposeAsync method and they don't even include it as a class method in their [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection.htm)

Comment: That's an argument against your claim - Oracle's driver is so bad everyone uses Pomelo now. It didn't even support `async` until recently, it faked it. As for `it just uses using without await` that's no argument at all. The doc page doesn't even contain the word `await`. Does that mean we should use any async operations?

Comment: Moreover, IDbConnection interface doesn't implement IAsyncDisposable, only IDisposable, which is another hint, that DisposeAsync should not be used with DbConnection

Comment: Which is  .NET Framework 1.0 interface, so doesn't count either. There was no `async` in 2002. `DbConnection` was added in .NET Framework 2.0

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well, if you look at the source code of any DbConnection, you will see that DisposeAsync only calls synchronous methods and returns manually constructed empty ValueTask. The method itself is not even async, so why use it? What are the async benefits here?

Comment: That's wrong too. Again, if that was the case, no async method should be used because all the abstract class async methods are actually synchronous. That's not the case. The abstract classes provide default implementations in case a provider doesn't implement some feature. Providers that *do* implement the feature override the methods. Oracle's MySQL drivers didn't implement the async methods for example until recently

Comment: I've actually answered a lot of MySQL-related questions from people that found out their async calls blocked. I know what's in DbConnection, what the methods do, and what the method docs and remarks say. I know how Oracle tried to fake async execution at first (they used a background thread).